# Basis of a vector space using basis of tensor product and universal property

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

I already proved that if $\{u_i\}$ is a basis for $U$, $\{v_i\}$ basis for $V$, then $\{u_i \otimes v_j\}$ is a basis for $U \otimes V$.

Now, I am trying to prove that if $g:U \times V \to W$ is bilinear and $\{u_i\}$ is a basis for $U$, $\{v_i\}$ basis for $V$, then $\{g(u_i,v_j)\}$ is a basis for W. I am doing this in order to prove that there is an isomorphism between $W$ and $U \otimes V$.

In particular, I want to show that a pair $(W,g:U\times V \to W)$, with $g$ bilinear, characterizes the tensor product $(U \otimes V,t:U\times V \to U \otimes V)$ up to isomorphism by showing that $\{g(u_i,v_j)\}$ is a basis for W. That way, for g bilinear there is an unique $\tau:U \otimes V \to W$ such that $\tau (u_i \otimes v_j)=g(u_i,v_j)$, which is an isomorphism because it carries a basis of $U\otimes V$ to a basis of $W$.

I think the proof comes from the fact that $\{u_i\}$ is a basis for $U$, $\{v_i\}$ basis for $V$, then $\{u_i \otimes v_j\}$ is a basis for $U \otimes V$, but I don't see it clearly.

Comment: Well, $g \equiv 0$ is bilinear but $W$ can have non-zero vectors. Don't you have more hypothesis?

Comment: What if $g$ is a bilinear *form*?

Comment: I added some details to explain better what I am trying to do!

Comment: If $g$ is onto, then any element of $w \in W$ can be expressed as $w=g(u,v), u \in U, v \in V$. Can you exploit the bilinearity of $g$ to rewrite $w$ as a linear combination of $\{g(u_i,v_j)\}$?

Comment: @eigenchris but to express $w$ as a linear combination of $g(u_i,v_j)$ I need g onto and it is not part of the hypothesis

Comment: If $g:U \times V \to W$ if bilinear, the UMP assures the existence of a unique LINEAR map $\phi :U \otimes V \to W$ such that $\phi \circ \otimes =g$. So $g$ is probably not an isomorphism. Or do you want to somehow find an isomorphism $g$? The whole point of the UMP is that it already characterizes $\otimes $ completely since $\phi $ is unique.

Comment: I've re-read your question and re-thought things. You want to show that $W$ is isomorphic to $U \otimes V$ through the linear map $\tau(u_i \otimes v_j) = g(u_i,v_j)$, correct? This would imply that $\tau$ is bijective. But if we take $g=0$ as Ivo suggested, $\tau$ is clearly not bijective in the general case. Perhaps what you really want to show is that, given $g$, $\tau$ is unique?

Comment: @eigenchris, but given $g$, $\tau$ is unique by universal property

Comment: @jggarita That's correct. And I think this universal property is the only meaningful statement you can make about the relationship between the three functions $g$, $\tau$, and $\otimes : U \times V \rightarrow U \otimes V$. You cannot guarantee that any of these maps are isomorphisms in general.